# C++20 converting between string/u8string and string_view/u8string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

C++20 introduced `char8_t` and accordingly `u8string`, `u8string_view` etc. for mainly supporting cleaner interfaces and better differentiation between narrow execution and utf-8 character sets.

One of the downsides is that the old code might not work any more.

Say I have interfaces which work with **utf-8 encoded** `std::string` / `std::string_view` (from C++17).

If I want to adopt the implementation to the C++20 using `std::u8string / std::u8string_view` but leave the interfaces at the moment to the `std::string`, the easiest way to convert back and fort between `string/string_view` and `u8string/u8string_view` would be using `reinterpret_cast`, for ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    u8string u8s = u8"ä";
    // string s = u8"ä"; OK in C++17, NOK in C++20
    string s(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(u8s.c_str()));
    // or string s(u8s.cbegin(), u8s.cend());
    cout << s << endl;
    u8string u8s2(reinterpret_cast<const char8_t*>(s.c_str()));
    // or u8string u8s2(s.begin(), s.end())

    // string_view
    u8string_view u8sv = u8"ö"sv;
    string_view sv(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(u8sv.data()), u8sv.size());
    cout << sv << endl;
}
```

Do you see some problem with this approach, or have some better suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char8_t` has the same size and alignment as `char`, and is implicitly convertible.

Instead of casts and `c_str()`, just use the iterator constructor.

```cpp
u8string u8s = u8"test";
string s(u8s.cbegin(), u8s.cend());
```

Comment: You might still need reinterpret_cast for views. But for owning strings the iterator constructor will do the right thing.